# meta.*.stackexchange.com/privileges doesn't exist

Tags: discussion, per-site-meta, privileges

I just noticed that there is no /privileges page for the per-site metas.  Same for meta.superuser.com/privileges.  Is this an oversight or is there a reason behind it?  It seems to me that they should have their own since reputation requirements are different from the parent site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't want another set of shadow world meta /privilege faqs to maintain, update, and validate for accuracy.

The parent site /privilege faqs should suffice, and the /faq on the per-site meta does cover the actual reputation values themselves.

Comment: Well, right now, Meta.Gaming's privileges do not appear to match Gaming's privileges... unless you're telling me I should file another bug about that.  To be more specific, I have the Close option on Meta.Gaming but not Gaming.

Comment: @RBemrose It's specific to Meta Gaming. I've [already reported it](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1250/reputation-requirements-unchanged-for-the-meta-site). The other 3 live sites do not have this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing there aren't privilege pages for the [per site metas](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/new-per-site-metas/) as the reputation is the same as the parent site.  Therefore I would assume if you have the privilege on the parent site then you have the privilege on the meta.

Comment: In that case the page should redirect to the parent privileges page.

Comment: @ChrisF -I agree it probably should. I don't haz teh code tho :)