# Reputation link leads to a Page Not Found on per-site metas

Tags: bug, status-completed, privileges, per-site-meta

Jeff says in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67638/meta-stackexchange-com-privileges-doesnt-exist) that they don't have the privileges page because it's not necessary on the per-site metas.

Then in [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67333/where-is-the-link-to-my-privileges-page/67830#67830), he says it is now linked through the reputation in the header. On the per-site metas this will lead to a Page Not Found.

Maybe I'm misunderstanding how this was implemented, but I'm guessing the reputation link on the meta.se sites should either lead back to the parent privileges or not be a link at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this was solved by just removing the reputation link on the meta sites.