# Clicking on rep score in meta leads to "page missing" (on Area 51 sites)

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta, stackexchange-2.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reputation link leads to a Page Not Found on per-site metas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67835/reputation-link-leads-to-a-page-not-found-on-per-site-metas)

I've checked this on [SeasonedAdvice](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/privileges), [AskUbuntu](http://meta.askubuntu.com/privileges), and [TeX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/privileges), and on all three there is a missing page:

From meta click on your rep-score (toolbar, near your username), you'll get a "missing page" page. This does *not* happen in [meta.stackoverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges), there you get a description of your privileges.

Either the link should be disabled, or it should point somewhere useful.

Comment: Duplicate of [Reputation link leads to a Page Not Found on per-site metas](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67835/reputation-link-leads-to-a-page-not-found-on-per-site-metas).

Answer (score 1):

Meta.stackoverflow.com has its own reputation, while all other metas inherit the reputation of the parent page. Therefore there are no privileges that could be earned in a SE meta page directly, they are only given according to the privileges and reputation of the parent site.

So one question would be: are privileges always given/earned at the same reputation level in meta and its parent, or do the privileges differ.

If the privileges follow parent privileges, the link could point to the corresponding parent privileges page. Only drawback: the link on the title will then lead you to the parent site, not back to meta.

Therefore I propose to have a special meta privileges page, that uses the reputation of the parent site, but have its own privilege levels. ('Reduced advertising' and 'Leave comments' come to mind.)