# Area51 doesn't have privileges?

Tags: support, status-completed, area-51, privileges

http://area51.stackexchange.com/privileges

I think that says it all. I'm just surprised there's no privileges associated with Area51 is all.

> Is this a dupe of [meta.*.stackexchange.com/privileges doesn't exist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67638/meta-stackexchange-com-privileges-doesnt-exist) ?

Comment: I don't think it's a dupe. A51 is a unique beast.

Comment: @PopularDemand ~ I didn't mean an _exact_ dupe, I just meant a dupe in spirit. But yes, I know A51 is it's own beast. I wouldn't doubt if it has pretty much a completely separate code-base from the rest of the SE sites.

Comment: Yeah, separate codebase is what I meant with "unique beast." I had to post here on MSO to get them to implement <kbd>Enter</kbd>-submission of comments over on A51.

Comment: Area51 is a fork of the SE codebase, so I would imagine the privileges system will get copied over at some point... but it probably isn't high priority, as rep is less meaningful/important on that site.

Comment: @JonSeigel ~ Yeah I was curious about that myself, if rep really had meaning there, aside from being connected with the rest of the sites ~~ PS: Thanks for the tag-help :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The page you linked shows a list of privileges; you don't see all the privileges you see in other Stack Exchange sites because the code for Area 51 is a fork of the normal code. For example, Area 51 is about proposals, not questions; this means the code needs to be altered to handle proposals where other SE sites handle questions.
The different code has effect on the privileges, but also the badges; for example, a badge like [Organizer](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/5/organizer) would not have any meaning on Area 51.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Wow, good revival attempt. ;) ~ Also, at the time I posted, I don't think there was a list of those there. Now that this is fixed, I think it's time to be closed.

Comment: I was actually looking for a question about the privileges users have on a SE site, and I noticed this question. I found strange nobody answered it, and I checked Area 51, noticing what I reported. `:-)`